# CodedUI not being able to identify the controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation

I had built a codedUI test script to test an application built on WPF consisting of 20 or so test cases. It was working all this while for around a year. But now all of a sudden it seems to have stopped. CodedUI does not identify my controls anymore. It was working till build number 1.x.x.8. and now since 1.x.x.9, none of the controls are being identified. It gets the button at times and does not click it. Because I can see it while debugging. At times it takes too long to find the control around 15 to 20 mins for each control. Any possible reasons why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds your application may have had changes to some of the automation related properties which are used for identification of UI controls in your tests. You could use a tool like Microsoft's' "Visual UIA Verify" to walk your applications Automation Element Tree and compare it with the search properties used in your tests (usually these properties are AutomationID(s) and Name(s) of each control).

Another option is to re-map one of the problem UI Controls into your UIMap and compare it with the old control mappings. These are the first two places I would start looking for changes.